# how to pass additional parametes to spider parse function in scrapy during web scraping

Tags: parsing, scrapy, parameter-passing

> I am trying to pass additional information to the parse function but it is giving a type error.
>
> > TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'body'
> > i am unable to resolve this issue.

```
    """
    return [scrapy.Request(url=website.search_url.format(prod), callback=self.parse,
                           cb_kwargs = {"body":website.body_xpath,"product_list":website.products_list_xpath,
                                 "names":website.products_name_xpath,"selling_price":website.selling_price_xpath,
                                 "market_price":website.market_price_xpath}) for website in websites for prod in modified_products]

    def parse(self, response):
            body = response.cb_kwargs.get("body")
            product_list = response.cb_kwargs.get("product_list")
            name = response.cb_kwargs.get("names")
            selling_price = response.cb_kwargs.get("selling_price")
            market_price = response.cb_kwargs.get("market_price")

    """
```

Comment: You need to update the signature of your `parse` method accordingly: `parse(self, response)` → `parse(self, response, body)`

Comment: thanks a lot. @Gallaecio

Answer (score 0):

> I forgot to write those names in parse function definition, after adding them i am getting the correct result. Thanks for having a look at it.

```
    """
    return [scrapy.Request(url=website.search_url.format(prod), callback=self.parse,
                           cb_kwargs = dict(body = website.body_xpath, product_list  = website.products_list_xpath,
                                  name  = website.products_name_xpath, selling_price = website.selling_price_xpath,
                                  market_price  = website.market_price_xpath)) for website in websites for prod in modified_products]

    def parse(self, response, body, product_list, name, selling_price, market_price):
            body = response.cb_kwargs["body"]
            product_list = response.cb_kwargs["product_list"]
            name_ = response.cb_kwargs["name"]
            selling_price_ = response.cb_kwargs["selling_price"]
            market_price_ = response.cb_kwargs["market_price"]
    """
```